# Normed linear space

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

In Walter Rudin's Complex Analysis, it states that  by definition$$\|\Lambda\|=\text{sup}\{\|\Lambda x\|: x\in X, \|x\|\leq1\}$$
 and then later he shows that 
$\|\Lambda x\|\leq \|\Lambda\|\|x\|.$
But, the only thing I know is $\|\Lambda\|\geq\|\Lambda x\|$.

How to show that indeed $\|\Lambda x\|\leq \|\Lambda\|\|x\|.$

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$, that inequality is trivial.

In the other cases, $x=\lVert x\rVert\times\frac x{\lVert x\rVert}$. Since, $\left\lVert\frac x{\lVert x\rVert}\right\rVert=1$ and $\Lambda$ is linear,$$\lvert\Lambda x\rvert=\lVert x\rVert\left\lvert\Lambda\frac x{\lVert x\rVert}\right\rvert\leqslant\lVert x\rVert\lVert\Lambda\rVert.$$

Comment: Since, $\lVert\frac x{\lVert x\rVert}\rVert=1$ then $\lvert\Lambda\frac x{\lVert x\rVert}\rvert\leq\lvert\Lambda\rVert$?

Comment: Sure, by the definition of $\lVert\Lambda\rVert$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that
$$
\|\Lambda\|=\sup_{\substack{x\in X\\x\ne0}}\frac{\|\Lambda x\|}{\|x\|}
$$
by noticing that
$$
\left\|\frac{1}{\|x\|}x\,\right\|=1
$$